# Invoke an AWS Lambda function with file buffer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, buffer, invoke, payload

I am doing some manipulation on files using AWS Lambda.

I am dealing with **not enough memory** in my Lambda function.

1. In the first Lambda function I save a file to S3.
2. Then it sends a payload with the file url to the second Lambda function.
3. The second Lambda function downloads the file from S3 and continues manipulating the file.

I would like to directly send the buffer from the first function to the second function by sending the payload directly in the file buffer, rather than sending the file via S3.

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: it can be 30 MB

Comment: I don't think there is any way to pass such a big payload more efficiently than through s3. If it was less than 256KB or 1MB maybe you could use SQS or Kinesis.

Comment: Why are you handing-off to a second Lambda function? Are you hitting the 15-minute limit? How often are you triggering these functions? At some point, it might be better to use EC2 or Fargate.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory assigned to the Lambda function to avoid the "not enough memory" errors?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the size of my function is close to 256mb that is not allowed by aws

Comment: @JohnRotenstein and for combining pdf i hummus.js its a large size npm so i put this in another func